# PyPI - folder inside the package folder not getting uploaded

Tags: python, csv, setuptools, file-handling, pypi

I am uploading a package to PyPI which has the following structure:

```
packagefolder/
├── packagefolder/
│    ├── Data/
         ├── file1.csv
         ├── file2.csv
         ├── file3.csv
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── PythonScript.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
```

The **init**.py contains only :

```
 from package.PythonScript import PythonScript
```

The **PythonScript.py** contains code to access **file1.csv** in the **Data** folder.
It worked locally and even while uploaded and installed, the path works fine.

But the folder Data/ is **not seen in the locally installed** package file.

HOW CAN I INCLUDE THE **DATA** FOLDER IN THE LOCALLY INSTALLED PACKAGE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+include+data

Comment: `package_data={'packagefolder': ['Data/*.csv']}`

Comment: Thanks! It worked <3